# Multiple lines observation in DT

Tags: r, split, shiny, dt

I need to split an observation on a row into multiple lines and still remainig with just only a row.

For example

```
source<-data.frame("MEASURE"=c("First","First","Second"),"DATE"=c("2017-11-02","2017-12-12","2017-05-15"))
source<-source[source$MEASURE=="First",]
source<-droplevels(source)
```

Then I get  the DATES with levels()

```
y<-paste(levels(as.factor(cf$DATE)),collapse=",")
```

And then realize another DF:

```
s1<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=1, ncol=2))
s1[1,1]<-"Date"
s1[1,2] y
```

Which gives:

```
    X1                               X2
1 Date            2017-11-02,2017-12-12
```

but I need something like this

```
    X1                               X2
1 Date                       2017-11-02
                             2017-12-12
```

The words to be splitted could be 1,2 or more.
The df is just for summary and it will be used on shiny with DT::renderdataTable()

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you need `library(tidyr); separate_rows(dat, X2, sep=",")`

Comment: @akrun separate_rows will separate the values in X2 along new rows. I just need a "lines separation" insede the same row. It'is justa formatting issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the argument `escape` might be a solution. You can read about this argument at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ section 2.9. And substitute the commas for break lines:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
s1$X2 %>% str_replace_all(pattern = "[,]", replacement = "<br/>")
datatable(s1, escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: That works perfectly!!!!Thank you! Just one thing: str_replace_all is from package stringr..

Comment: @PaoloPolCristoforetti Consider accepting the answer if you found it useful